# Why does the use of typed variable make this code work

Tags: scala

This works

```
trait SomeTrait {   
  type T   
 def write2( s: String): T 
}

case class C() extends SomeTrait {  
  type T = String   
  override  def write2(s:String): T = s }
```

But this does not

```
trait SomeTrait {  
  def write2[T]( s: String): T 
}

case class C() extends SomeTrait {   
 override  def write2(s: String): String =s }
```

To my reasoning, they ..seem similar. Why specifically does the compiler give a "method does not override anything" error? IS there a way of making this work?

Comment: Please name differently your type parameter and your base trait, it will be a little less confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Your trait definition in the second snippet does not mean that implementations of it must have a method `write2` for some type `T`, but that it must have a method `write2` which takes a type parameter `T`.

That means that, if you have a value `v: SomeTrait`, you should be able to do

```
val stringed: String = v.method2[String]("foo")
val inted: Int = v.method2[Int]("foo")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use this definition:

```
trait T {  
  def write2[T]( s: String): T 
}
```

Consider some client using this trait. For example:

```
def doSomething(t: T): Unit = {
  val s: String = t.write2[String]("hello")
  val n: Int = t.write2[Int]("world")
  val d: Double = t.write2[Double]("!")
  println(s + n.toString + d.toString)
}
```

I don't know what the values of s, n, and d would be, but in theory that would be a perfectly valid usage of the trait, from the compiler's perspective. So in order to truly override that `write2[T]` method, you would have to provide valid behavior for *all* possible types `T`.

Compare that to:

```
trait T2 {   
  type T   
  def write2( s: String): T 
}
```

Or even:

```
trait T3[T] {
  def write2(s: String): T
}
```

Then when callers use it:

```
def doSomething(t: T2): Unit = {
  val x = t.write2("hello") // always returns type t.T
}

def doSomething[T](t: T3[T]): Unit = {
  val x = t.write2("hello") // always returns type T
}
```

There's only one possible type that can be returned, once you have a specific instance of that trait. So to override that method, you need only override the behavior for that one type.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles:

```
trait T {
     def write2[T]( s: String): T
 }

 case class C() extends T {
     override  def write2[T](s: String): T =s.asInstanceOf[T]
 }
```

`write2` returns a T, not a `String` (hence the reason why your second override does not work and the necessity in the code above for the ugly cast)

Comment: This compiles, but not in an at all useful way.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov The goal was not to make it "useful" but explain why `T` not being a type `String`, the override of the OP would not compile